# Parse prn file to Html Table

Tags: java, html

I have to parse .prn file to HTML table.

I have problem with couple columns - between columns is only one whitespace - I cannot use multiple whitespace as a splitter. Also beetween two segments columnname is one whitespace but it should be treated as one record. How can I parse it correctly?

Comment: Looks like you will need to use the String column value (String index) and compare it to hard-coded constants.

Comment: Since it looks like each column is a fixed width, i.e., a fixed number of characters wide, you could simply extract the fixed-width substring for each column, then trim any leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize a custom Split method which would split each PRN file line based on the data column widths then do whatever you like with the split data as it is read in:

The method might look something like this:

```
public static String[] splitStringToChunks(String inputString, int... chunkSizes) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int chunkStart = 0, chunkEnd = 0;
    for (int length : chunkSizes) {
        chunkStart = chunkEnd;
        chunkEnd = chunkStart + length;
        String dataChunk = inputString.substring(chunkStart, chunkEnd);
        list.add(dataChunk.trim());
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

And you might use this method something like this (as I said, **do whatever you like** with the split PRN data):

```
// Try With Resources used here to auto-close BufferedReader.
try (
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("DataFile.prn"))) {
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().equals("")) { continue; }
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Method called with supplied file data line and the widths of
        // each column as outlined within the file.
        String[] parts = splitStringToChunks(line, 16, 22, 9, 14, 13, 8);
        for (String str : parts) {
            sb.append(sb.toString().equals("") ? str : "; " + str);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

And with the PRN file data example you provided the above example usage will display within the console window:

```
Name; Address; Postcode; Phone; Credit Limit; Birthda
Johnson, John; Voorstraat 32; 3122gg; 020 3849381; 1000000; 19870101
Anderson, Paul; Dorpsplein 3A; 4532 AA; 030 3458986; 10909300; 19651203
Wicket, Steve; Mendelssohnstraat 54d; 3423 ba; 0313-398475; 93400; 19640603
Benetar, Pat; Driehoog 3zwart; 2340 CC; 06-28938945; 54; 19640904
Gibson, Mal; Vredenburg 21; 3209 DD; 06-48958986; 5450; 19781109
Friendly, User; Sint Jansstraat 32; 4220 EE; 0885-291029; 6360; 19800810
Smith, John; Břrkestraße 32; 87823; +44 728 889838; 989830; 19990920
```